Crashes when trying to get an id of a button that has been generated programmatically
I have an android application that generated 5 list of 5 numbers.

Secondly after clicking "Select Numbers", it will remove duplicate numbers and will print out all the numbers generated as buttons.

My program crashes on this code of MainActivity.kt
val generatedNumbersCollected: Button = findViewById(R.id.root)

generatedNumbersCollected.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }

I am assuming that R.id.root is null, therefore it crashes. I am looking for a way to resolve this issue. What could be a possible solution?
MainActivity.kt
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import kotlin.random.Random

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

private var concat: Set<Int> = emptySet()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)     {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val generateButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonGenerate)
    val selNumbers: Button = findViewById(R.id.selectNumbers)

    val numberGenerated: TextView = findViewById(R.id.numberGenerated)
    val numberGenerated2: TextView = findViewById(R.id.numberGenerated2)
    val numberGenerated3: TextView = findViewById(R.id.numberGenerated3)
    val numberGenerated4: TextView = findViewById(R.id.numberGenerated4)
    val numberGenerated5: TextView = findViewById(R.id.numberGenerated5)
    val collectedNumbers: TextView = findViewById(R.id.collectedNumbers)


    //var addBtn: Button? = null
    //linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)

    generateButton.setOnClickListener {
        val randomNumbers = generateSequence {
            Random.nextInt(1..70)
        }.distinct().take(5).sorted().toSet()
        val randomNumbers2 = generateSequence {
            Random.nextInt(1..70)
        }.distinct().take(5).sorted().toSet()
        val randomNumbers3 = generateSequence {
            Random.nextInt(1..70)
        }.distinct().take(5).sorted().toSet()
        val randomNumbers4 = generateSequence {
            Random.nextInt(1..70)
        }.distinct().take(5).sorted().toSet()
        val randomNumbers5 = generateSequence {
            Random.nextInt(1..70)
        }.distinct().take(5).sorted().toSet()

        concat = concatenate(
            randomNumbers,
            randomNumbers2,
            randomNumbers3,
            randomNumbers4,
            randomNumbers5
        )


        numberGenerated.text = randomNumbers.toString()
        numberGenerated2.text = randomNumbers2.toString()
        numberGenerated3.text = randomNumbers3.toString()
        numberGenerated4.text = randomNumbers4.toString()
        numberGenerated5.text = randomNumbers5.toString()
    }

    selNumbers.setOnClickListener {
        numberGenerated.text = "none"
        numberGenerated2.text = "none"
        numberGenerated3.text = "none"
        numberGenerated4.text = "none"
        numberGenerated5.text = "none"
        collectedNumbers.text = concat.toString()
        createAndAddView()

        //val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SelectNumbers::class.java)
        //startActivity(intent)
    }

    /*val generatedNumbersCollected: Button = findViewById(R.id.root)
    generatedNumbersCollected.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }*/


}

    private fun createAndAddView()
{
    val root = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)
    lateinit var button: Button

    val array: IntArray = concat.toIntArray()

    for ((index, i) in array.withIndex()) {
            button = Button(this).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            id = index + 1
            text = i.toString()
        }
        root.addView(button)

    }
    val flow = findViewById<Flow>(R.id.flow)
    flow.referencedIds = (1 .. array.size).toList().toIntArray()


}


}

private fun Random.nextInt(range: IntRange): Int {
return range.first + nextInt(range.last - range.first)
}

private fun concatenate(
randomNumbers: Set<Int>,
randomNumbers2: Set<Int>,
randomNumbers3: Set<Int>,
randomNumbers4: Set<Int>,
randomNumbers5: Set<Int>
): Set<Int> {
return randomNumbers + randomNumbers2 +     randomNumbers3 + randomNumbers4 + randomNumbers5
}

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selectedRandom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Selected Random" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberGenerated5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Number 5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/collectedNumbers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="none" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGenerate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Generate" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectNumbers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Numbers" />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
            android:id="@+id/flow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:flow_horizontalGap="8dp"
            app:flow_maxElementsWrap="5"
            app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
            app:flow_verticalStyle="packed"
            app:flow_wrapMode="aligned" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

Here is the logcat:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                Process: com.example.randomgenerator, PID: 19302
                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.randomgenerator/com.example.randomgenerator.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
                                                                                                    at com.example.randomgenerator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:84)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 


R.id.root is a layout not a button so it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  The buttons added by createAndAddView are child views of the layout.  Furthermore, the added button views would not be accessible until after user clicks on the selNumbers button - not in onCreate.

Looks like I need to look for another way to create buttons, and having id for each button in XML.

@AlejandroH - Please share the stack trace of the crash.

I posted the logcat.

I tried to copied your code and can solve that with the button can clicked and get the results with do a change on this function
private fun createAndAddView() {
        val root = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)
        lateinit var button: Button

        val array: IntArray = concat.toIntArray()

        for ((index, i) in array.withIndex()) {
            button = Button(this).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                id = index + 1
                text = i.toString()
                // add this code
                setOnClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Clicked ${i}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            root.addView(button)
        }
        val flow = findViewById<Flow>(R.id.flow)
        flow.referencedIds = (1..array.size).toList().toIntArray()
    }

But, actually my recommendations is implement recyclerview will make your code more clean and simple rather than generate flow like this. Happy to code :)

It seems to work as I expected it to, the code makes sense.
